How to repeat a terminal in grammar environment of syntax* package?
I want to type EBNF text in latex. The solution I found is to use the grammar environment of syntax* package.
But no word describes how to repeat a terminal in the doc.
The EBNF text I want to type is <id list> ::= <id> { ',' <id> }. It means the comma and id after the comma should be repeated for zero or more times.
The MWE is like the following. It does not work.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nounderscore, rounded]{syntax}

\begin{document}
\begin{grammar}

<id list> ::= <id> { ',' <id> }

\end{grammar}
\end{document}

The result is 

Does anyone have a more detailed doc of syntax* package?

You may want to look at the naive-ebnf package.

Well, a naïve attempt would be
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nounderscore, rounded]{syntax}

\begin{document}

\begin{grammar}
<id list> ::= <id> \{ ',' <id> \}
\end{grammar}

\end{document}


